# Laptop shuts down by closing the lid when plugged, not goes to sleep as it should

Tags: linux, laptop, debian, sleep, power-management

I have installed Debian 8.0 Jessie with Gnome on my HP ProBook 430 G2. The weird problem is that when I close the lid while laptop is plugged, it shuts down and does not go to sleep as it does when unplugged. I don't know what setting to change to fix this. The power settings has nothing to say regarding this.